# how to set navigation based on login in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The module.config has navigation defined as follows

```
'navigation' => array(
            'default' => array(
                    array(
                            'label' => 'Home',
                            'route' => 'home',
                    ),
                    array(
                            'label' => 'Report',
                            'route' => 'report',

                    array(
                            'label' => 'Logout',
                            'route' => 'logout',
                    ),
            ),
    ),
```

In my layout.phtml

```
<?php
    echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->renderMenu(
        $container = null,
        $options = array(
            'ulClass' => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'indent'  => 16,
        )
    );
?>
```

How can i hide the logout  in the navigation in module.config when no identity is not set?

Now whether login or not i am able to see the logout , how to restrict that through navigation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove logout url from navigation if user isn't login.

try:

```
//Module.php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{               
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $sm = $application->getServiceManager();
    if (user not login) {
        $container = $sm->get('navigation');
        $logoutPage = $container->findBy('route' , 'logout');
        $container->removePage($logoutPage);
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.navigation.containers.html)